# Place mutliple TextViews on the front of ImageView

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-imageview, android-constraintlayout

I'm using CardView for recycleView's item
My CardView contain one ImageView and multiple TextView
I want to place mutliple TextView on the front of ImageView with xml

1. center of image view (no problem, I did it)
2. bottom right
3. bottom left
4. top right
5. top left

Here my xml's item of recycle View with TextView in center of ImageView but I can't place in the four other position.

For clarification see the below image:
[this image for place TextView in center of imageView and what I need to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t00t0.jpg)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/card_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/stadium_photo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_stadium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/stadium_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="Mohammad"
            android:textColor="#ffffcd"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    
    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout) you achieve this in no time.

You will want to set layout that looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars[10]" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**It will look like this:**

[image]

Comment: worked for me, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using combination of alignParentEnd/Start + alignParentTop/Bottom in TextViews? It seems that changing your TextView to

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/stadium_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="Mohammad"
            android:textColor="#ffffcd"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
```

would do the trick and align TextView to upper left corner(or upper right, depending on where the start is :) )

Answer (score 0):

`CardView` is a `FrameLayout` ([Documentation of CardView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView)) so you don't even need the wrapping `RelativeLayout` to achieve what you want. Try this complete example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars[0]" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start|top"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top|end"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|start"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="TextView" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use ConstraintLayout inside CardView.
Add image as first element and set constraints:
layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
(the same for Top, Bottom and End)

and then define position for text views

1. `Start_toStartOf="parent"`, `Top_toTopOf="parent"`
2. `End_toEndOf="parent`, `Top_toTopOf="parent"`
3. `Start_toStartOf="parent"`, `Bottom_toBottomOf="parent"`
4. `End_toEndOf="parent`, `Bottom_toBottomOf="parent"`

Answer (score 0):

you just have to set a fixed height(like 100dp) for the relative layout and image view
then just use align_parent_bottom and ...